# Порционный импорт CSV в MySQL на PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Как сделать импорт большого csv файла (порядка 100мб)

Что бы при каждом запуске скрипта импортировалось по 1000 строк

Есть такой код, помогите доработать, или может есть у кого готовое решение

```html
<?php
$host      = 'localhost';
$db_name   = 'db_name';
$db_user   = 'db_user';
$db_passwd = 'db_passwd';
$file      = 'file.csv';
$delimiter = ';';
$verbose   = true;

try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_passwd, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));
 $db->exec("set names utf8");
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO oc_review (`id`, `text`) VALUES (?, ?) ");

    if (!file_exists($file)){
        throw new Exception("File $file not found!");
    }
    $f = fopen($file, 'r+');

    $data = array();
    while($data[]=fgetcsv($f, 0, $delimiter)){}

    if (empty($data)) {
        throw new Exception("Empty data. Check the source file.");
    }
    $i=0;
    foreach ($data as $entry) {
        if (!is_array($entry) || empty($entry[0])) {
            continue;
        }
        if ($verbose){
            print "\nProcessing entry ID: ". $entry[0];
        }
        $stmt->execute($entry);
        $i++;
    }
    print "\n\n$i rows were successfully processed";

}
catch (Exception $e){
    print "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: https://oooportal.ru/?cat=article&id=854 будет хорошим решением для вас читать файл построчно, каждый раз двигаясь на 1000 строк

Comment: В коде сможете продемонстрировать?

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю два возможных решения, хотя это скорее наброски, из которых вы можете придумать свою, нормальную реализацию. Обращаю ваше внимание на то, что второй вариант, вероятно работать не будет. А вот первый вполне реалистичен.

```php
// Например вот так можно читать файл
$linecount = 0;
$buffer = [];
$file = @fopen("yourfilepath", "r");
while(!feof($file)) { 
    if($linecount > 999){
        //Вставить в базу работаем с массивом буффер
        //Обнуляем переменные
        $linecount = 0;
        $bufer = [];
    }
    $buffer[] = fgets($file);
    $linecount++;
} 
fclose($file); 
//Или вот так например
$startline = $_POST['startln'];
$buffer = [];
$linecount = 0;
$file = @file("yourfilepath");
while($linecount < $startline+999){
    $i = $startline+$linecount;
    if($s=$file[$i]){
        $buffer[] = $s;
        $linecount++
    }
    else{
        break;
    }
}
//Как написал Эдуард ниже в комментариях, проверяем буффер на пустосту
if (! empty($buffer)){
//Сделать что то с массивом buffer
}
```

Дело в том, что в первом варианте мы просто в потоке читаем построчно файл, т.е мы не подгружаем его сразу полностью в буфер. Во втором варианте, мы выгружаем файл в массив, а от туда уже обращаемся к строкам.

Comment: А что произойдёт с "остатком" данных, которые не попадут под соответствие условию `if($linecount > 999)` ? Они ведь будут потеряны. Что бы этого избежать, понадобится ещё одна проверка после цикла, нечто вроде `if (! empty($buffer))`.

Comment: @Эдуард вы правы, просто человек просил примерное решение, я с телефона его добавил :) Сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 0):

Читать не вариант - каждый раз будет загрузка всех 100мб.

Правильнее разбить эти 100мб на части - например, как раз по 1000 строк чтобы было и импортировать поочередно - например, по имени файла, в котором содержится нумерация.

Comment: Да думал об этом